# How to change the HTML5 "md-" prefix in Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to change this Angular Material prefix tags `"md-"`:

```
<md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
```

to:

```
<custom-button>{{title1}}</custom-button>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: start here ... https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/button/button.js

Comment: did my answer help you a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the `md-button` in angular material and change it to `custom-button`. I found the code of this directive as bellow

```
angular
    .module('material.components.button', [ 'material.core' ])
    .directive('mdButton', MdButtonDirective);
```

Now based on your requirement, you can start from below

```
angular
    .module('material.components.button', [ 'material.core' ])
    .directive('customButton', MdButtonDirective);
```

My suggestion: Do not modify in angular material file. Create a new directive named `customButton`